# Promises in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to convert some callback to Promises in NodeJS using Bluebird or Q but I didn't success.
Can anyone be nice and give me an example how can I convert the above code to Promises?

Thanks in advance

Adrian

```
function httpResponse(request, response) {
    fs.readFile('views/main.ejs', 'utf-8', function readFile(error, file) {
        if (error) {
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            response.write('EJS ERROR');
            response.end();
        } else {
            // get domains data from db needed for main page
            dbHandle.queryDB({}, "domains", function dbQueryDB(error, result) {
                var ejsData = {name: "Cav"};
                if (error) {
                    response.write('DB ERROR');
                    response.end();
                } else {
                    ejsData.domains = result;
                    // get machine type data from db needed for main page
                    dbHandle.queryDB({}, "type", function dbQueryDB(error, result) {
                        if (error) {
                            response.write('DB ERROR');
                            response.end();
                        } else {
                            ejsData.type = result;
                            //respond index.html
                            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                            response.end(ejs.render(file, ejsData));
                        }

                    });
                }


            });


        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `bluebird`, have a look at the [promisification section](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification).

Basically you'd do something like:

```
var fs = require("fs");
Promise.promisifyAll(fs); 
Promise.promisifyAll(dbHandle); //do this globally if it is global, not every request!
```

Then your code would be something like:

```
    function httpResponse(request, response) {
        fs.readFileAsync('views/main.ejs', 'utf-8')
        //Special catch only for EJS errors. ONce past this point in the chain, will not hit again.

        .then( function(file){
            return dbHandle.queryDBAsync({}, "domains");
        } )
        .then( function(domains){
            ejsData.domains = domains;
            return dbHandle.queryDBAsync({}, "type");
        })
        .then( function( types ){
            ejsData.type = types;
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            response.end(ejs.render(file, ejsData));
        })
        .catch( function(error){
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            response.write('EJS ERROR'); //or DB errors, add some handling if the error message is important
            response.end();
        });
    }
```

I chained these all together to keep the code more flat. You could nest the promises as well. But Promisification is the way to go here with establish libraries.

**Edit**
To keep `file` in scope, try a Promise setup like this. Note the nested Promise.

```
function httpResponse(request, response) {
        fs.readFileAsync('views/main.ejs', 'utf-8')
        //Special catch only for EJS errors. ONce past this point in the chain, will not hit again.


        .then( function(file){
            return dbHandle.queryDBAsync({}, "domains")
            .then( function(domains){
                ejsData.domains = domains;
                return dbHandle.queryDBAsync({}, "type");
            })
            .then( function( types ){
                ejsData.type = types;
                response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                response.end(ejs.render(file, ejsData));
            })
        .catch( function(error){
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            response.write('EJS ERROR'); //or DB errors, add some handling if the error message is important
            response.end();
        });
    }
```

An alternative to that is to track the `file` variable outside the Promise chain. When `readFileAsync` is returned, store the `result` to `file` (that you declared out of the scoop), and you can use it a few steps later.

Comment: By the way, I got "file is not defined" at "response.end(ejs.render(file, ejsData));". I think because this is not a closure and because of that it can't see the file variable.

Comment: Ah, that's the trick with chaining promises like that - the `.then()` variables go out of scope. I'll edit my answer for you to show how to nest less, but keep things in scope.

Comment: Yes, I already store the result of the file to a variable that was declared out of scoop but I didn't think it was a reliable solution.